# Unable to get correct output in linux script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ram

```
#!/bin/bash
ac = "(free | grep Mem | awk '{print $4/$2 * 100.0}')"
echo "$ac"
```

I wanted to get the remaining(free) percentage of RAM usage as output storing in variable for further processing.
Instead m getting $ac output as

```
    total        0.00
```

Please help

Comment: This can't be your real script, since you can't have spaces around the assignment `ac = `.

Comment: sorry cant understand you , what you wan to say ?

Comment: @NikhileshYadav He's saying it needs to be `ac="$(free | grep Mem | awk '{print $4/$2 * 100.0}')"` not `ac = "(free | grep Mem | awk '{print $4/$2 * 100.0}')"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
ac="$(free | grep Mem | awk '{print $4/$2 * 100.0}')"
echo "$ac"
```

works fine for me.

(BTW, `awk` can do grep's work too:

```
free | awk '$1=="Mem:" { print 100*$4/$2; }'
```

)

Comment: please copy the above code, save it to .sh file and execute, you will see the same result that i have shown you

Comment: @NikhileshYadav I'm not seeing that. What does a standalone `free` output on your system to stdout and stderr?

Comment: Can you include the output of `cat -v test.sh` in that screenshot?

Comment: @NikhileshYadav And what part of "it needs to be `ac="$(free | grep Mem | awk '{print $4/$2 * 100.0}')"` not `ac = "(free | grep Mem | awk '{print $4/$2 * 100.0}')"`" did you not understand?

Comment: yes now i understand that i need to put '$' , thanks for your help :)